# form_for won't pass id Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, parameters, form-for

I have the following strange situation:

I call my edit action through a `link_to`,

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', companies_edit_path(:id => company.id)%>
```

And everything is fine. I mean, i reach the edit page with the correct dates loaded. This is my edit page:

```
<%= form_for @company ,:url => {:action => :update, :controller => :companies, :method => :put} do |f| %>
  <% if @company.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@company.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @company.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>


<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="form-group">

                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <%= f.text_field :name, size: 40 %>
                        </div>
                    </div>
...
...
</form>
<% end %>
```

i took off all the things into the form_for, I don't think they are important.
Now , when i click on submit i should go in my update action (as you can see in the form_for declaration). **But it said to me that isn't able to find the company cause it doesn't have id passed.**
this is my controller:

```
 def edit
        @company = Company.find(params[:id])
  end


def update
        @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.update_attributes(params[:company])
        format.html { redirect_to companies_index_path, :notice => 'Aggiornato.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @company.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

these are my routes:

```
  get  "companies/index"
  get  "companies/new"
  get  "companies/search"
  get  "companies/edit"
  post "companies/create"
  put  "companies/update"
  devise_for :users
  resource :calendar, :only => [:show]
  resources :events
  root :to => 'home#index'
```

Do you see anything strange?

**EDIT:**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"l4FVwvB66aGnYCvCTMXb3r/LB8DpKz7huV/DCkySO80=",
 "company"=>{"ragione_sociale"=>"Beretta salame",
 "id_forma_giuridica"=>"3",
 "id_settore"=>"1",
 "indirizzo"=>"sdsdsd",
 "citta"=>"sdsss",
 "cap"=>"",
 "id_provincia"=>"1",
 "telefono"=>"",
 "email"=>"",
 "id_dimensione"=>"1",
 "id_numero_dipen"=>"1",
 "id_certificazione"=>"1",
 "id_contattato"=>"1",
 "id_stato"=>"1",
 "richiamare"=>"",
 "id_gestito"=>"1",
 "prodotto"=>"",
 "id_consulenza"=>"1",
 "id_software"=>"1",
 "references_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"nome"=>"vito monn",
 "id_funzione"=>"11",
 "telefono"=>"aaa",
 "email"=>"aaaaa",
 "cognome"=>"aaaa",
 "id_titolo"=>"3",
 "cellulare"=>"aaaaa",
 "id"=>"8"}},
 "nome_r"=>"",
 "id_funzione_r"=>"1",
 "telefono_r"=>"",
 "email_r"=>"",
 "cognome_r"=>"",
 "id_titolo_r"=>"1",
 "cellulare_r"=>"",
 "note"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Completa",
 "method"=>"put"}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error in the question?

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CompaniesController#update

Couldn't find Company without an ID

Comment: Can you also post the params that are generated?

Comment: i edited the first post. But they are the parameters i passed by form

Comment: Try changing `@company = Company.find(params[:id])` to `@company = Company.find(params[:company][:id])`

Comment: i tried before but nothing changed